# Mongoose query from userid or based on ips

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

All i have is an userid and this query:

```
  return gamelog.find({userid: userid).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
```

with the following model:

```
new Schema({
    userid : String,
    ip: String,

});
```

The result would at least give me one or more IP. Then I'm in need to query those IP's to check if any other user has been on that IP address.

How could I modify this query, so I get all IP's with that userid, or any userid, from one of those IP's?

The ideal result would result in all userid`s IP addresses, and all other users that have been on any of the IP's that the userid has been on.

edit:

sample document:

```
{
time: "1507127113173",
ip:"::1",
others: 0,
url:"/api/gameapi?action=getweapon",
userid:"59d4ef435048380ff4abd683"
}

{
time: "1507127113173",
ip:"::1",
others: 0,
url:"/api/gameapi?action=getweapon",
userid:"59d4ef43504833333333380ff4abd683"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

The below query will filter all the documents for "userid" followed by `$group` to get collection of "ips" and `$lookup` to join to bring all the users sharing the same ips as queried user.

`$unwind` other user's document and `$group` on other user's id and collect ips followed by final group to get collection of user id and ips.

```
db.gamelog.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "userid": userId
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "ips": {
        "$push": "$ip"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "gamelog",
      "localField": "ips",
      "foreignField": "ip",
      "as": "otherusers"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$otherusers"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "otherusers.userid": {
        "$ne": userId
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$otherusers.userid",
      "ips": {
        "$first": "$ips"
      },
      "otheruserips": {
        "$push": "$otherusers.ip"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "ips": {
        "$first": "$ips"
      },
      "otherusers": {
        "$push": {
          "userid": "$_id",
          "ips": "$otheruserips"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: What will the variable ipuser hold?
cause, its currently undefined.

Comment: Sorry it should be ipuserf. Updated answer.

Comment: Yeah tried that. But then every row in the logs are getting an users property. How can I modify your answer to only give me up adresses from that user and the users that used it ?

Comment: Something like the response of ips: array of ips, other users: array containing user and the ips the user have a match of ( must be same ips as userid)

Comment: will confirm asap. currently i get an empty output on it.

Comment: I can verify the query  if you can add some sample document to the post.

Comment: Works for me on 3.4 version( required ). I get the output `{_id:null, ips:[":1"], otherusers:[{userid:"59d4ef43504833333333380ff4abd683", ips:[":1"]}]}`

Comment: can i see ur model schema?

Comment: it works if i remove unwind @Veeram , but it sems like it dosent catch the unique ips. http://prntscr.com/h0b7au

Comment: Sorry I don't know mongoose. I've noticed you have incorrect lookup's `from` attribute value in the query that you've linked.. It should be the name of the collection `gamelogs`.